Recovering old, deleted videos on an iPhone
So, very short backstory...
My brother is going through a messy breakup, his ex is using their child to make him do whatever she wants. He has decided to go down the legal route as she constantly denies him access for trivial reasons and he is sick of it.
To aid him in the legal stuff, he used to record arguments and other interactions, however, she once found him doing it and made him delete them before being able to leave. She then deleted them from his deleted folder.
He wants to know if there is any way possible to get these videos back, one in particular he believes will be very helpful. This, however was back in July. He has looked at software online such as one called Fone Paw, and others which claim to be able to find old deleted files from years ago... For a fee. However, I am skeptical of this. If anyone here says it is legit, I am happy to pay the fee for him, but wanted to know firstly, are these sites likely to be able to retrieve the data? Phone repair shops always claim to be able to do this too, again for large fees whether they get it or not. If there is a way I can do it for him, I would rather do it.
Feel free to ask for anything that needs clarification in comments and I will do my best to answer.
Some clarifying points:

The question about the linked software is just a side-question of "is it legitimate?"
My brother says he hasn't filled the internal memory on his phone since the video was deleted
It was deleted back in June

The main question I am asking here is if it is possible the video data is still retrievable, and if so, what are the ways to look for that data?

Welcome to Ask Different. Does your brother have a backup of his iPhone (either on his computer or in iCloud)?

@jaume He does have an iCloud, but he couldn't find it on there when he looked

Whoever closed this question, I thought it is always polite to provide an explanation as to why you did it. This way, the question can be edited to be on topic. As it is, I don't understand what is off topic about it. I stated the problem, I am not asking for off site resources, they were mentioned as possible things that have been tried. I was asking if this specific problem has a solution.

See Meta question on this https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4298/do-you-guys-not-give-new-people-hints-on-improving-questions

@nohillside I have edited the question after your Meta answer. Hopefully that should be enough for re-opening
